# Css. Doesn't work text-overflow: ellipsis

Tags: css

I have something like this:

```
<div>
  <span>
    text text text text text text
  </span>
</div>

div{
  width:100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  line-height: 12px;
  height: 16px;
  position: relative;
  overflow:hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

span{
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden; 
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

And ellipsis doesn't work.
I do not necessarily need to use position: absolute, but as result I should have text, that doesn't expand div and truncated width ellipsis.

P.S. Width for div is included for sample, in reality div width is unknown.

Comment: Your jsfiddle is different than your question.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/t8bnfr9s/3/

Comment: See [this](https://semicolon.dev/tutorial/css/text-overflow-ellipsis-doesnt-work) tutorial, it actually covers most cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no idea why you need absolute position for the span tag, but it's doesn't matter here.

Span tag should have the "width" css-rule to solve your problem. For your example:

```
span {
   width:100%;
}
```

So every time you want to use `overflow:ellipsis` option you have to specify the width for target element.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `width: 100%` to your `span`:

```css
div{
  width:100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  line-height: 12px;
  height: 16px;
  position: relative;
  overflow:hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

span{
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden; 
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span>
    text text text text text text
  </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`text-overflow: ellipsis;` affects when it does not have enough space for the text.

```css
div {
 width: 100px;
 border: 1px solid black;
 line-height: 12px;
 height: 16px;
}
span {
 overflow: hidden;
 text-overflow: ellipsis;
 display: block;
 white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span>
    text text text text text text
  </span>
</div>
```